# Скрипт выдергивает слово из текста рендомом, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html

Извените, пожалуйста, если что-то подобное уже было направте меня пожалуйста в нужную тему.
 Сразу оговорюсь, что плохо знаю JavaScript и плохо знаком с HTML. Делаю сейчас, можно сказать по словарику.
 Проблемме такая.
 Вот скрипт

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function fun1() {
n=0;
m1=0; m2=0; m3=0;
str1="";str2="";str3="";str4="";
for (var i=0; i<document.all.length; i++) 
    { n=Math.random(); 
    if (document.all.item(i).tagName=="P") 
        {str2=document.all.item(i).innerText;   // str2 будет содержать текст последнего найденного абзаца
        m2=i;}              // m2 - номер последнего найденного абзаца
    if ((document.all.item(i).tagName =="P") && (n>0.7) && (n<0.8))
        {str1=document.all.item(i).innerText;   // str1 будет содержать текст случайного абзаца или пустой текст
        m1=i;               // m1 - номер случайного абзаца
        i=document.all.length;}
    }
if (str1=="") {str1=str2;  m1=m2};      // если str1 пуст, то str1 примет значение str2, а m1- значение m2
n=1+ Math.round(str1.length/2)*Math.random();  //случайный номер позиции символа в строке
m2=str1.indexOf(" ",n)+1;           //номер символа, следующего за первым пробелом в строке после позиции n
m3=str1.indexOf(" ",m2);                //номер первого пробела в строке после позиции m2
str2=str1.substring(m2,m3);         // str2 - случайное слово из строки
for (i=0; i<str2.length;i++) str3=str3+"*";     //str3 - зашифрованное слово
str4=str1.substring(0,m2)+str3+str1.substring(m3,str1.length);          // абзац с зашифрованным словом
document.all.imgUpr.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin","<P align='left'>"+str4+"</P>"); //вставка в документ абзаца с зашифрованным словом
xword=prompt("Какие символы или слово скрыты знаками **** ?","");       //запрос на ввод зашифрованного слова 
if (str2==xword) alert("Верно!"); else alert ("Неверно. Это слово: "+str2);     //проверка и вывод результата
i=document.all.imgUpr.sourceIndex;      //получение индекса элемента, находящегося после вставленного абзаца
document.all.item(i-1).outerText="";        //удаление вставленного абзаца
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Смысл скрипта: Выдергивает абзац из текста, вытаскивает из него слово, вместо слова вставляет звездочки и ждет от пользователя ввода этого слова. Короче это типа упражнения на память. Вот только у меня один модуль в руках. Т.е. как все это дело вывести незнаю. Знаю что после запуска показывает окошко (обычно такое, в которое урл вводишь, чтобы не прокручивать текст). 
 Вот как это все организовать незнаю.
 Плюс ко всему, еще и скрипт как то надо переписать, чтобы он из абзаца выдерал не все подрят рендомом, а именно те слова которые надо. Например есть определение:

```
<p><strong>Денежные  измерители </strong>используются для обобщенного отражения объектов учета в единой  денежной оценке. Необходимо отметить, что  отдельные виды имущества и обязательств не подлежат оценке в натуральных  и трудовых измерителях, например, денежные средства, дебиторская и кредиторская  задолженность, капитал, кредиты и займы.</p>
```

Из него надо выдрать только "Денежные измерения" а не любое слово.
 Помогите пожалуйста ооооооочень надо... Вопрос, практически жизни и смерти, зашиваюсь с этими кодами.

Answer (score 2):

```
<p id="para"><strong>слово1 </strong>слово2</p>

js:
function swap(x)
{
    var x = x.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0], r = x.innerHTML;
    x.innerHTML = '***';
    return r;
}
var slovo = swap(document.getElementById('para'));
alert(slovo);
```

Это по поводу "выдрать слово".

Comment: Но как его использовать? Точнее через что выводита на экран? 
В принципе немного понятно. Щас попробую что-нибудь сделать...
Спасибо За помощь!